# Admin and User table

Tags: mysql

How to create tables in the database for users who well be admin who have his own website to adminstrate the android application and the user who well be student that well use the application ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to have an seperate table for admin and your end users. You can have an common 'users' table. In the users table you can have an column something like 'admin' which is of type boolean which can help you in differentiating between your admin users and end users.

Admin users can have 'boolean true' and the other end users can have 'boolean false'. Based on the user's admin column vaue you can branch out your further logic of your app

Comment: alternatively have a separate table called admins and add the user id here of the user who is an admin, if there are more than 2 roles, create a roles table with role_id and role_name, a user_roles table with user_id and role_id and have these refer to the users table